# How to fix Angular bug requiring user to click a separate element before choosing a second mat chip

Tags: html, angular, mat

Here is the [link](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/examples) for an example of the issue I will attempt to describe. In the chips autocomplete example, click the text box to select a new fruit.

Now, before clicking anywhere else, click again on the text box as you did before.

This should result in no options showing up. The issue here is that the user must either begin keying in a new selection or first click another element in the window before matchip will show the options to choose from. I am wondering if there is a way to fix this issue. I would like a user to be able to choose a selection from the list and then immediately click the text box as they had before and make a new selection.

Comment: Do you mean the autocomplete mat option list doesn't come back up after selecting the option (because the cursor is already in the input box)? It's kind of hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes, I believe what you're describing is my issue. To attempt to elaborate: once an option is selected, if the user immediately tries clicking inside the text box, no options will appear. Only after clicking another element and then back in the text box will those options appear again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't post your code and you mention the example on the material site I'm going to do it as a fork of the [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/rlqkbolgkylq?file=app%2Fchips-autocomplete-example.ts) they have on their site.
But this will allow you to open the autocomplete panel again despite having had the cursor there and choosing an option previously.

```
// Using MatAutocompleteTrigger will give you access to the API that will allow you to
// to open the panel or keep it open
...
@ViewChild(MatAutocompleteTrigger, {static: false}) trigger: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
...

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    fromEvent(this.fruitInput.nativeElement, 'click')
      .pipe(
        tap(() => {
          this.trigger.openPanel()
        })
      ).subscribe()
  }
```

Link to the full stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sb38ig

Comment: Running into an error where the console reads this.fruitInput is undefined. Although in my code, it says this.positionInput is undefined. I'm looking for a way to post my code here.

Comment: For some reason, I couldn't get the code from stackblitz to work in my application. Using this,
```document.getElementById('firstName').click();```
however, worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using mat-chip-list inside an outer *ngFor iterating over a FormArray.

Here is what I'have done. It's pretty efficient :

```
<input 
    #validatorInput
    #operationTrigger="matAutocompleteTrigger"
    [formControl]="contactCtrl"
    [matAutocomplete]="auto"
    [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
    (blur)="contactCtrl.setValue(''); validatorInput.value='';"
    (click)="contactCtrl.setValue(''); validatorInput.value=''; operationTrigger.openPanel()">
```

The trick is

1. Always clear your html input and your (shared) `formControl` with an empty **and not null** value each time the `blur` and `click` events occur.
2. Do NOT do this 'clear' on the input `focus` event. (Because when you delete the last chip, the input is auto-focus and you will have the famous `Expression has changed after it was checked`.
3. Call `operationTrigger.openPanel();` when the user click on the input

- Setting `contactCtrl.setValue('');` allows your autocomplete panel to be automatically opened when you call `operationTrigger.openPanel()`
- Setting `validatorInput.value='';` is just a way to properly sync your formControl with the html input to ensure a good UX/UI behavior.
- Inside my formArray, the formControl is the same for all the inputs but it does not matter since the user can only manipulate one input at a given time

Comment: thanks, saved the day